# EF Core 3.1 migrations not playing nice with npgsql and nodatime

Tags: npgsql, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1, nodatime

Anyone know what's causing this exception? Have asp.net core 3.1 and infrastructure library .netstandard2.1. Setup npgsql with nodatime. Followed their instructions however on running add migration I'm greeted with this nastiness, not sure why?

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
> services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalTypeMappingSourcePlugin
> Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType:
> Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlNodaTimeTypeMappingSourcePlugin':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ISqlGenerationHelper' while
> attempting to activate
> 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlNodaTimeTypeMappingSourcePlugin'.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IMethodCallTranslatorPlugin
> Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType:
> Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime.NpgsqlNodaTimeMethodCallTranslatorPlugin':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ISqlExpressionFactory' while
> attempting to activate
> 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime.NpgsqlNodaTimeMethodCallTranslatorPlugin'.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IMemberTranslatorPlugin Lifetime:
> Singleton ImplementationType:
> Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime.NpgsqlNodaTimeMemberTranslatorPlugin':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ISqlExpressionFactory' while
> attempting to activate
> 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime.NpgsqlNodaTimeMemberTranslatorPlugin'.)

Comment: Can you post a minimal code sample?

Comment: Sorry it was my bad. I fixed the issue already. now dealing with something else. nodatime Duration not recognized by npgsql in ef core configuraiton. its never easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad. Forgot the below statements in startup.cs. They can be set anywhere in the ConfigureServices method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     ...

     services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql();
     services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsqlNodaTime();

     ...
}
```